# Reclassify button disabled in Tridion CMS version SDL Web 8.6

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

We are trying to reclassify the component to use another keyword but "Insert" and "Reclassify" buttons are disabled. This was working on Tridion 2011 version of CMS.

We need to have this enabled to process further

Can Anyone please check this issue and share the resolution.

Please Find the attached screenshot for your reference.[image]

[image]

Comment: I think Reclassify only applicable if there is a component already associated some keywords if you select that component, you will get that option to reclassify

Comment: @Velmurugan, thanks for commenting. Yes the keyword is associated with some of the Components, We want to reclassify the keyword with some other one but the Insert and Reclassify buttons are Disabled.

Comment: But there are no components listed in the GUI screenshot you show above? Does the logged-in user have access to the relevant components/schema? Can they open one of the components that is associated with the keywords ... perhaps add that to this post?

Comment: @Dylan..MarkSaunders, The user have necessary privileges to Classify/Reclassify the keywords to associated with the components. Please find the screen shot which you are referring.

Comment: if you click area in the left pane, then doors area in the right pane - does it work then? there is some noted GUI oddness with category/keyword selection and the source pane/click.

Answer (score 2):

I think this works the other way around. 
If you are trying to classify Components with a common Taxonomy Keyword, then simply search for your components in a folder or with the search functionality. Then select multiple components, right click and Classify, choose the keyword you want to tag those components with.

When you choose Classify on a Keyword (as opposed to a Component), it means you are trying to tag that keyword with another one. Essentially only possible when your keyword has a metadata keyword field, to associate it with another keyword from another taxonomy for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, we are not classifying the components with a common taxonomy Keyword. We are selecting the Keyword from the category and then able to view the components which are associated in bottom view pane. So by selecting the component we need to Reclassify the keyword with other value. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are Reclassifying the selected component with another Keyword, not Reclassifying the keyword itself. However what you describe works fine for me in 8.5, thus you may want to open a support ticket just so that CloudOps can check if your issue can be reproduced on 8.6.